# C - get path of .c file

Tags: c, path, relative-path

I have the following .c file:

`/home/eamorr/project1/eamorr.c`

I compiles fine and its exe is located at:

`/home/eamorr/project1/a.out`

Now, I have a php file at:

`/home/eamorr/project1/a/b/c/eamorr.php`

It needs to call `a.out`

```
<?php
$cmd=__DIR__."../../../a.out";
$result=`$cmd`;
?>
```

Here's the `eamorr.c` program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
 setuid (0);

 char temp[2048];
 char pwd[1024];

 realpath(argv[0],pwd);


 sprintf(temp,"/bin/bash %s/doMagic.sh",pwd);
 system((char *)temp);

 return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately the pwd variable contains the wrong path!!!

`/home/eamorr/project1/a.out/doMagic.sh`

How do I get rid of the a.out bit from the path? I don't program in C very often and I've been at this for over an hour now...

Comment: You might consider doing a chdir from PHP before calling the program and avoiding all the directory trickery entirely.

Comment: The reason I'm using C is because I need a web user to be able to execute a privileged program. Yes, I know... The user is authenticated and the user is restricted to an IP range.

Comment: I didn't say not to use a C program. You can do a `chdir()` before executing the C program and then call `./doMagic.sh` instead of trying prefix it with the full path.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, what you would like to get is something like:

```
/home/eamorr/project1/doMagic.sh
```

First of all, I dont generally do this kind of path handling in C. However, I had a quick look and it seems that you could use the `dirname()` functionality. Have a look here http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/basename.3.html. Please be careful with this because I would imagine that these are Linux stuff, not sure how you would do it in DOS.

Comment: Yes, but is `dirname` the path of the `a.out` exe or the path of the calling .php file? I can't figure it out...

Comment: I suspect it's irrelevant how to do it in DOS, because nobody still uses DOS, and in particular, @Eamorr is almost certainly not running PHP on DOS.

Comment: @Andres - `dirname()` works great! Thank you so much! I did try `basename()`... That didn't work. But dirname() does...

Comment: As I said, if what you want is `/home/eamorr/project1/doMagic.sh`, then I would imagine you would do something like: `realpath(argv[0],pwd); myPath = dirname(pwd);`

Comment: @immibis It is true that the question suggests the program is running on Linux (or some other unix-based system), but I just thought it is important to point out that this solution would probably not work on a Windows machine. However, I am definitely not a Windows user so I have no clue.

Comment: @AndrésAG DOS is not Windows.